# Parsing the first column of a csv file to a new file

Tags: bash, csv, sed, awk, cut

Operating System: OSX
Method: From the command line, so using sed, cut, gawk, although preferably no installing modules.

Essentially I am trying to take the first column of a csv file and parse it to a new file.

Example input file

```
EXAMPLEfoo,60,6
EXAMPLEbar,30,6
EXAMPLE1,60,3
EXAMPLE2,120,6
EXAMPLE3,60,6
EXAMPLE4,30,6
```

Desire output

```
EXAMPLEfoo 
EXAMPLEbar
EXAMPLE1
EXAMPLE2
EXAMPLE3
EXAMPLE4
```

So I want the first column.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
awk -F"," '{print $1}' in.csv > out.txt

awk -F"," '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++)}' in.csv > out.txt

awk -F"," 'BEGIN { OFS="," }' '{print $1}' in.csv > out.txt

cat in.csv | cut -d \, -f 1 > out.txt
```

None seem to work, either they just print the first line or nothing at all, so I would assume it's failing to read line by line.

Comment: As I've pointed out in answer to your previous(and very similar) question, my FOSS project http://code.google.com/p/csvfix/ does exactly this, is easier to use for parsing CSV than awk et al, and works on OSX.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Your last option works perfectly for me:

```
$ cat > in.csv  # Then pasted the example input followed by Ctrl+D:
EXAMPLEfoo,60,6
EXAMPLEbar,30,6
EXAMPLE1,60,3
EXAMPLE2,120,6
EXAMPLE3,60,6
EXAMPLE4,30,6
[Ctrl+D]
$ cat in.csv | cut -d, -f1
EXAMPLEfoo
EXAMPLEbar
EXAMPLE1
EXAMPLE2
EXAMPLE3
EXAMPLE4
```

Maybe line endings are biting you here? If the file has DOS-style or even old-Mac-style line endings, this might cause strange behaviour. Try running `file in.csv` and see what it comes up with.

```
$ file in.unix.csv
in.unix.csv: ASCII text
$ file in.dos.csv
in.dos.csv: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

If the latter is your situation, use the `dos2unix` tool to convert the file.

Edit: On OS X, it seems [`flip` is what you want](http://damonparker.org/blog/2006/01/05/convert-mac-line-endings/).

Comment: You were spot on about the line endings, fixed it now.

Answer (score 17):

I copy-pasted your sample input, saved it as in.csv, and then ran your first line,

```
awk -F"," '{print $1}' in.csv > out.txt
```

and it worked perfectly, like so:

```
$ emacs in.csv
$ cat in.csv 
EXAMPLEfoo,60,6
EXAMPLEbar,30,6
EXAMPLE1,60,3
EXAMPLE2,120,6
EXAMPLE3,60,6
EXAMPLE4,30,6
$ awk -F"," '{print $1}' in.csv > out.txt
$ cat out.txt 
EXAMPLEfoo
EXAMPLEbar
EXAMPLE1
EXAMPLE2
EXAMPLE3
```

This is in Terminal.app on OS X 10.5

Comment: This is odd, awk has been giving me issues recently.

Answer (score 13):

For me, cut produces expected result:

```
cut -d, -f1 < in.csv > out.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

If Perl is an option:

`perl -F, -lane 'print $F[0]' in.csv > out.txt`

These command-line options are used:

- `-n` loop around every line of the input file
- `-l` removes newlines before processing, and adds them back in afterwards
- `-a` autosplit mode – split input lines into the `@F` array.  Defaults to splitting on whitespace.
- `-e` execute the perl code
- `-F` autosplit modifier, in this case splits on `,`

`@F` is the array of words in each line, indexed starting with `$F[0]`