# RegEx - How to extract second matches using grep

Tags: regex, grep

How to extract second numbers in this text using grep command in ubuntu.

```
14219,98.2,31-s,19225
39219,92.7,31-s,29225
39219,38.7,31-s,29225
```

ouput desired :

```
98.2
92.7
38.7
```

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Possibly a duplicate of this post: [Parsing the first column of a csv file to a new file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652494/parsing-the-first-column-of-a-csv-file-to-a-new-file)

In your case, you can use `cat file.txt | cut -d, -f2` to extract the second column.

Comment: `cat` is not necessary. Just `cut -d, -f2 file.txt` is enough